# GraphicsAdapter lacks a definition for CheckDeviceMultiSampleType

Tags: xna, graphics, antialiasing

The MSDN is really confusing about this, with all their different versions of XNA jumbled together for my google results. All I want to do is find out, in XNA 4.0, what antialiasing modes are supported by the display adapter. Supposedly, this involves calling GraphicsAdapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType(), but that function isn't defined. What should I be using in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method was removed in XNA4 since it was no longer needed since we now have the reach and hi-def profiles. You can now just [prefer multisampling or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager_members%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) and the framework will set an appropriate `MultiSampleCount` if possible. You can still set this value yourself [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.presentationparameters_members%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) but setting it too high won't cause an error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976069.aspx

> In XNA Game Studio 3.1, use GraphicsAdapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType
>   to query the hardware for multisample support. In XNA Game Studio 4.0
>   Refresh, set the PreferMultiSampling property on the
>   GraphicsDeviceManager class to true to enable multisampling for the
>   back buffer. This will be ignored if the hardware does not support
>   multisampling.

Btw if you have problems with MSDN. In the top left of the current article you're viewing you can select the proper version (if available).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. It was that clear to me that it was unnecessary to check for different types.